# Unity3d Render openGL FBO to texture in android (java)

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I'm trying to make a plugin in Android (java) for Unity3D to render using an OpenGL texture, get the native pointer and maping a Quad in Unity. So far my Unity code is simple:

```
    // Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
    context = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    surface2Unity = new AndroidJavaObject("com.everywoah.surface2unity.Surface2Unity"); 

    int i = surface2Unity.Call<int> ("getTextureID");
    t =Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture (1280, 720, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false,false, new IntPtr(i));
    t.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
    t.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Repeat;
    debug.text = "" + i;
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.mainTexture = t;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //transform.Rotate(1f,1f,1f);
    surface2Unity.Call ("draw");
}
```

And in Java I have:

```
public MyRenderer(){
    initGL();
    initFBO();
}

private void initGL(){
    GLstatics.checkGlError("initGL_S");

    String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
            "attribute vec4 aTex;\n" +
            "varying vec2 tex;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "    gl_Position = aPosition;\n" +
            "tex=aTex.xy;\n" +
            "}";

    String fragmentShader = "precision mediump float;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "void main(){\n" +
            "        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);\n" +
            "\n" +
            "}";

    mProgram         = GLstatics.createProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    maPositionHandle = GLES30.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
    maTexHandle = GLES30.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTex");

    GLstatics.checkGlError("initGL_E");

}


private void initFBO(){
    GLstatics.checkGlError("initFBO_S");


    GLES30.glGenFramebuffers(1, mFboId, 0);
    GLES30.glGenRenderbuffers(1, mRboId, 0);
    GLES30.glGenTextures(1, mTexId, 0);

    GLES30.glGenBuffers(1,buffer, 0);

    GLES30.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, mRboId[0]);
    GLES30.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES30.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 1280,
            720);

    GLES30.glBindFramebuffer(GLES30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFboId[0]);
    GLES30.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
            GLES30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, mRboId[0]);

    GLES30.glActiveTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexId[0]);
    GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLES30.glTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA, 1280, 720, 0,
            GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    GLES30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
            GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexId[0], 0);
    GLstatics.checkGlError("initFBO_E ");
}

public void draw() {
    GLstatics.checkGlError("draw_S");

    GLES30.glBindFramebuffer(GLES30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFboId[0]);
    GLES30.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

    GLES30.glViewport(0, 0, 1280, 720);

    GLES30.glClear(GLES30.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES30.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    mVtxBuf.position(0);
    GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);

    GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle,
            3, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, 4*(3+2), mVtxBuf);
    GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);

    mVtxBuf.position(3);
    GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(maTexHandle, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * (3 + 2), mVtxBuf);
    GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTexHandle);

    GLES30.glDrawArrays(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    GLstatics.checkGlError("draw_E ");
}
```

It should be a really simple code, just drawing a yellow rectangle in a blue background, and I can make it work in an Activity. The problem here is that my app looks like this:
[image]

From where I think I'm messing with openGL buffers already bound, cause the vertices of my rectangle are drawn but with a weird thing inside. I've tried saving them and binding them after the draw function but I'm having the same result. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? If possible I'd really like to solve this in Java, I have up to 0 experience using the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so the problem was I have to take control of EGLContex myself, I can't do the rendering in the same context than Unity so I needed this class:

```
public class SurfaceManager {

public final static String TAG = "TextureManager";

private static final int EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID = 0x3142;

// Contexto donde dibujar
private EGLContext mEGLContext = null;
// Contexto compartido entre hilos. Para poder pasar el FBO de un hilo a otro
private EGLContext mEGLSharedContext = null;
private EGLSurface mEGLSurface = null;
private EGLDisplay mEGLDisplay = null;

// La surface donde se va a dibujar
private Surface mSurface;

/**
 * Creates an EGL context and an EGL surface.
 */
public SurfaceManager(Surface surface) {
    EGLContext shared = EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext();
    if (surface == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    mSurface = surface;
    mEGLSharedContext = shared;
    Log.d("Surface2UnityDebug", "vamos al setup");
    eglSetup();
}

// Hace que la surface actual sea esta
public void makeCurrent() {
    if (!EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface, mEGLSurface, mEGLContext))
        throw new RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent failed");
}

// Cambia el buffer donde se está pintando por el de la surface. es decir, guarda lo que se haya pintado.
public void swapBuffers() {
    EGL14.eglSwapBuffers(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface);
}

/**
 * Sends the presentation time stamp to EGL.  Time is expressed in nanoseconds.
 */
public void setPresentationTime(long nsecs) {
    EGLExt.eglPresentationTimeANDROID(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface, nsecs);
    checkEglError("eglPresentationTimeANDROID");
}

/**
 * Prepares EGL.  We want a GLES 2.0 context and a surface that supports recording.
 */
private void eglSetup() {
    mEGLDisplay = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if (mEGLDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
        Log.d("Surface2UnityDebug", "unable to get EGL14 display");
        throw new RuntimeException("unable to get EGL14 display");
    }
    int[] version = new int[2];
    if (!EGL14.eglInitialize(mEGLDisplay, version, 0, version, 1)) {
        Log.d("Surface2UnityDebug", "unable to initialize EGL14");
        throw new RuntimeException("unable to initialize EGL14");
    }

    // Configure EGL for recording and OpenGL ES 2.0.
    int[] attribList;
    attribList = new int[]{
            EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
            EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
            EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
            EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
            EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID, 1,
            EGL14.EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
    int[] numConfigs = new int[1];

    EGL14.eglChooseConfig(mEGLDisplay, attribList, 0, configs, 0, configs.length,
            numConfigs, 0);
    checkEglError("eglCreateContext RGB888+recordable ES2");

    // Configure context for OpenGL ES 2.0.
    int[] attrib_list = {
            EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3,
            EGL14.EGL_NONE
    };

    mEGLContext = EGL14.eglCreateContext(mEGLDisplay, configs[0], mEGLSharedContext, attrib_list, 0);
    checkEglError("eglCreateContext");

    // Create a window surface, and attach it to the Surface we received.
    int[] surfaceAttribs = {
            EGL14.EGL_NONE
    };
    mEGLSurface = EGL14.eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL14.EGL_DRAW);
    checkEglError("eglCreateWindowSurface");


}

/**
 * Discards all resources held by this class, notably the EGL context.  Also releases the
 * Surface that was passed to our constructor.
 */
public void release() {
    if (mEGLDisplay != EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
        EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE,
                EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
        EGL14.eglDestroySurface(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface);
        EGL14.eglDestroyContext(mEGLDisplay, mEGLContext);
        EGL14.eglReleaseThread();
        EGL14.eglTerminate(mEGLDisplay);
    }
    mEGLDisplay = EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY;
    mEGLContext = EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT;
    mEGLSurface = EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE;
    mSurface.release();
}

/**
 * Checks for EGL errors. Throws an exception if one is found.
 */
private void checkEglError(String msg) {
    int error;
    if ((error = EGL14.eglGetError()) != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS) {
        Log.d("Surface2UnityDebug", msg + ": EGL error: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(error));
        throw new RuntimeException(msg + ": EGL error: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(error));
    }
}}
```

And methods:

```
    // Guarda el estado actual
public void saveRenderState() {
    mSavedEglDisplay     = EGL14.eglGetCurrentDisplay();
    mSavedEglDrawSurface = EGL14.eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL14.EGL_DRAW);
    mSavedEglReadSurface = EGL14.eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL14.EGL_READ);
    mSavedEglContext     = EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext();
}

// Carga el estado guardado
public void restoreRenderState() {
    if (!EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(
            mSavedEglDisplay,
            mSavedEglDrawSurface,
            mSavedEglReadSurface,
            mSavedEglContext)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent failed");
    }
}
```

That way I can call saveRenderState(), makeCurrent(), draw() and restoreRenderState() and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Java side:

```
public int loadImageReturnTexturePtr(String imagePath, int width, int heigh) {
    Log.d("unity", "loading image1: " + imagePath);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
    Log.d("unity", "Bitmap is: " + bitmap);

    int textures[] = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    int textureId = textures[0];

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, heigh, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap,0);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    Log.d("unity", "texture id returned: " + textureId);

    return textureId;
}
```

unity c# side:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    AndroidJavaObject mImageLoader = new AndroidJavaObject ("com.dvision.load.LoadTexture");
    Texture2D texture2D = new Texture2D (2048, 2048, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

    int texPtr = mImageLoader.Call <int> ("loadImageReturnTexturePtr", "/sdcard/Lfront.jpg", 2048, 2048);
    Debug.Log ("texture pointer? " + texPtr);
    Texture2D nativeTexture = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture (2048, 2048, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false, true, new System.IntPtr (texPtr));
    texture2D.UpdateExternalTexture (nativeTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr ());
    gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture = texture2D;
}
```

you can use the function: `Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture`
It is so simple to do it.

Comment: Can you tell me reverse of this ? i mean generate image from intPtr i get from Unity